# Implicit coercion of a value of type Vector.<X> to an unrelated type Vector.<X>

Tags: actionscript-3, vector, types, flash-builder

I've got line of code

```
var enemies:Vector.<Unit>    = _map.getEnemiesForFraction(_fraction);
```

where `_map.getEnemiesForFraction(_fraction)` is

```
public function getEnemiesForFraction(fraction:String):Vector.<Unit>
{
    return _enemiesByFraction[fraction];
}
```

It compiles and works fine, but FlashBuilder keep annoying me with error

> `Implicit coercion of a value of type Vector.<Unit> to an unrelated
>   type Vector.<Unit>.`

Why? How to get rid of this? Neither restart nor clean, doesn't work.

Comment: It would be useful to know what type _enemiesByFraction is. If it is a dictionary, it should work. If it is anything other than a dictionary, then it probably won't (at least not out of the box).

Comment: _enemiesByFraction is `Object` that contains `Vector.<Unit>` by `String` key. But actually it seems that FlashBuilder doesn't like `getEnemiesForFraction` function return value type. Yep. Just tried it. No luck.

Comment: this probably won't change anything but might make the error go away `... = _map.getEnemiesForFraction(_fraction) as Vector.<Unit>`

Comment: Just tried it in IntelliJ IDEA and it worked fine. When you say "it compiles and works fine" but FlashBuilder gives you that error, what do you mean? Where do you see that error? At compile-time? Run-time? Is it an inline code-hint?

Comment: Try changing return statement like so: `return _enemiesByFraction[fraction] as Vector.<Unit>;`.